# Confusion of small detail with uniformly magnetised sphere?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, boundary-conditions, ferromagnetism

I have a rather pedantic question regarding the boundary condition for a uniformly magnetised sphere in vacuum. I know how to derive the effective magnetic charge density $-\rho_m=\nabla\cdot{\bf M}=\nabla^2\Phi$. Applying the divergence theorem to $\nabla\cdot{\bf M}$, I obtain
$$\iiint\nabla\cdot{\bf M}{\text{ d}}^3 r=-\iiint\rho_m {\text{ d}}^3 r=\iint{\bf M}\cdot{\text{ d}}^2{\bf r}.$$
By analogy with the electric field, the divergence theorem should give me $\sigma_m=-{\bf M}\cdot{\bf n}$. However, the correct boundary condition does not have the minus sign. Where did it go? Thanks!

Comment: Is your question basically "why does $\iiint \rho_m d^3 V \neq \iint \sigma_m d^2 a$?"

Comment: Yes, or rather where does the minus sign (the one in front of $\iiint \rho_m dV$) go?

Answer (score 0):

The effective magnetic charge density is not $\rho_m = \nabla \cdot \bf{M}$ but $\rho_m = -\nabla \cdot \bf{M}$.  This ensures that in the absence of free currents, the auxiliary field $\vec{H}$ obeys the equations
$$
\nabla \times \mathbf{H} = 0, \qquad \nabla \cdot \mathbf{H} = \rho_m = - \nabla \cdot \mathbf{M},
$$
and so the field $\mathbf{H}$ can be written as a gradient of a potential satisfying Poisson's equation with $\rho_m$ as a source.  (The latter equation follows from the fact that $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{B} = 0$.)

Comment: Hello Michael, there was a typo in my first equation and I have edited it, so there may be a miscommunication; I did include a minus sign in my divergence theorem though, and I don’t know how to get rid of it when applying the divergence theorem. May I seek your advice? Thank you!